# How can I ask DOMDocument to not parse html special characters?

Tags: php, dom, special-characters

(sorry for my english) I have this code

```
$content2 = file_get_contents( $url );
$dom2 = new DOMDocument();
@$dom2->loadHTML( $content2 );
$classname = 'b-details_text';
$finder = new DomXPath($dom2);
$parent = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");
$ps = $parent->item( 0 )->getElementsByTagName( "p" );

$text = $ps->item( 0 )->textContent;
```

where $content2 contains this part

```
...
<div>
<div class='b-details_text'>

<p> ...It&#8217;s the best way to get good love karma flowing &#8212; and you&#8217;ll be surprised by how good it makes you feel right away, too... </p>
</div>
</div>
...
```

and I want get
    `...It&#8217;s the best way to get good love karma flowing &#8212; and you&#8217;ll be surprised by how good it makes you feel right away, too...`
 in $text

but instead, I am always getting something like this `...ItтАЩs the best way to get good love karma flowing тАФ and youтАЩll be surprised by how good it makes you feel right away, too...`

How can I ask DOMDocument to not parse html special characters?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using htmlentities() on the node's text might solve your problem.

This solution doesn't prevent DOMDocument from parsing the html entities in the first place.

Try:

```
$text = htmlentities($ps->item( 0 )->textContent);
```

Comment: @Mher I updated the answer to use htmlentities() which might be a solution, but it still doesn't prevent DOMDocument from parsing the special characters.

Comment: thanks @myninjaname, it seems htmlentities is solution. By using this code ` $text = htmlentities( $ps->item( 0 )->textContent, (ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401), 'UTF-8' ); ` I am getting this result
` ...It&rsquo;s the best way to get good love karma flowing &mdash; and you&rsquo;ll be surprised by how good it makes you feel right away, too... `

Comment: &rsquo; instead of &#8217;
&mdash; instead of &#8212;

but it is fine for me, thanks again )